# WiFi Direct Hotspot Connection (KOTLIN/ANDROID)

Tags: android, kotlin, p2p, wifip2p, kotlin-android

I Create a Simple APP in Kotlin, when 1 device Click a button, Button goes to Create a Group of WiFi Direct, Its means WiFi Direct Hotspot and we can see it in WiFi list of any Device like below Code (**BUT DEVICE CONNECTED TO OUR WIFI DIRECT GROUP NOT HAVE INTERNET CONNECTION**):

```
manager = applicationContext.getSystemService(WIFI_P2P_SERVICE) as WifiP2pManager
channel = manager.initialize(this, mainLooper, null)
receiver = WiFiDirectReceiver(manager, channel, this)

intentFilter = IntentFilter().apply {
    addAction(WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION)
    addAction(WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION)
    addAction(WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION)
    addAction(WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION)
}

if (!isWifiP2pEnabled) {
    Log.e("P2P ACTIVITY", "error: cannot start wf hotspot. WifiP2p is not enabled\n")
    return
}

val ssid = "DIRECT-gg"
val password = "123456789"
var band = WifiP2pConfig.GROUP_OWNER_BAND_AUTO

val config = WifiP2pConfig.Builder()
    .setNetworkName(ssid)
    .setPassphrase(password)
    .enablePersistentMode(false)
    .setGroupOperatingBand(band)
    .build()

manager.createGroup(channel, config, object : ActionListener {
    override fun onSuccess() {
        isHotspotEnabled = true
    }

    override fun onFailure(i: Int) {
        Log.e("P2P ACTIVITY", "wf hotspot failed to start. reason: $i\n")
    }
})
```

But I have a Problem, when other Device Connected to this (WiFi Direct Hotspot), they **cant** Search in Internet, I mean their **Not Have Internet Connection**, I dont know WHY, tell me what should I Do or Use or Code?

I set All Permission its needs and Broadcast but still cant get Internet Connection to Who Devices Join our WiFi Direct Hotspot Group

I expect that when I Click the Button and the WiFi Direct Group is Created, Everyone who Connects to it will also have Access to the Internet

Comment: This is WiFi Direct, not WiFi Hotspot. It will not route your connection to anyone who's connected to it, but it's rather used as a means to exchange data like streams and files and establish socket connections, it is a standalone independent network with no links whatsoever to the actual internet.